# Should we have a community wiki question related to parsing file formats?

Tags: discussion

Following on from the discussion [here](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1439/should-we-consider-questions-about-parsing-file-formats-on-or-off-topic), [someone](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5440/concept3d) mentioned that some 3d file formats are poorly documented and suggested that if a game developer can give a better answer than a programmer (on say StackOverflow) then the answer should be found here.

From my experience, 3D file format parsing is quite difficult, but the reality is that most formats are easily parsed using [assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/), which in itself is quite a beast. I was recently trying to extract some skeletal animation from a collada (dae) file built using 3DS max and exported with it too. I had to parse the bone structure, along with the animations structure, and the answer [on Gamedev.stackexchange.com](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26382/i-cant-figure-out-how-to-animate-my-loaded-model-with-assimp) was pretty much my go-to for the entire project.

What I would suggest is keeping a community wiki style answer, with a few explanations similar to [the last one mentioned](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26382/i-cant-figure-out-how-to-animate-my-loaded-model-with-assimp), and pointing new users towards it?

Comment: See also: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1439/should-we-consider-questions-about-parsing-file-formats-on-or-off-topic

Answer (score 3):

That's the sort of thing that *external* wikis or sites would be good for, not StackExchange.

I am against this idea because it would set a precedent for allowing these kinds of "how do I get started" resource-gathering questions, and I don't think those questions fall into the purview of the questions that this site should host.